# Get SIM MSISDN & IMSI number in Windows Phone Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

Is it possible to get the SIM MSISDN & IMSI number in windows Phone app development?

I have gone through some of the Q/A but they all are asked a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You could get SIM MSISDN & IMSI number in Windows Phone Application. Please notice that you should manually edit your application Package.appxmanifest as follows:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

......

<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity" />
</Capabilities>
```

> The cellularDeviceIdentity capability allows apps to access cellular identification data.
>   Anyone may request access to these [capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#special-and-restricted-capabilities) for store submission.

You could use [`MobileBroadbandModem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.mobilebroadbandmodem) class to get all `CurrentDeviceInformation`, and the following is core codes.

```
using Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators;

......

public IReadOnlyList<SimCard> GetSimCards()
{
    var results = new List<SimCard>();

    var modem = MobileBroadbandModem.GetDefault();
    if (modem == null)
    {
        return results.AsReadOnly();
    }

    var account = modem.CurrentAccount;
    if (account == null)
    {
        return results.AsReadOnly();
    }
    var simCard = new SimCard();
    simCard.ICCID = account.CurrentDeviceInformation.SimIccId;
    simCard.IMSI = account.CurrentDeviceInformation.SubscriberId;
    simCard.MSISDN = modem.DeviceInformation.TelephoneNumbers;

    simCard.MCC = ExtractMCC(simCard.IMSI);
    simCard.MNC = ExtractMNC(simCard.IMSI);
    simCard.MSID = ExtractMSID(simCard.IMSI);

    results.Add(simCard);

    return results.AsReadOnly();
}
```

I have uploaded [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/SimCardTest) to git hub. Please check!

Comment: How can I get the reference of the windows.networking.networkoperators?

Comment: You could use [`Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators) name space directly !

Comment: I am not getting the MobileBroadbandModem class accessible in the code. I have added  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity" />
</Capabilities> this to the Package.appxmanifest.  But I am using VS2013 and making windows phone 8.1 app

Comment: Do I need to get any kind of permission to work on this?

Comment: In 8.1 I am not able to access the MobileBroadbandModem class

Comment: Exactly, The name space of  `Windows.Networking.NetworkOperators` is used in uwp!

Comment: You are right. I can use the same namespace in UWP 8.1. But I am not able to access MobileBroadbandModem  class.

Comment: There are no APIs in the Windows Phone SDK to retrieve this information. Mobile Operators have to work with their Microsoft contact\Support channels available for them. Form more your cold refer to [this case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1cd5e507-7fed-4c62-88b8-cc1544079357/sim-card-information-iccid-imsi-msisdn?forum=wpdevelop).