# Fetch phone number for Android, IOS and Windows Phone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I am working on a Xamarin forms project and want to fetch user's phone number from device.

Please anyone can guide me how can I fetch phone number for  Android, IOS and Windows Phone

Please suggest if any nuget package or third party library is available.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;

   mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);

   var Number = mTelephonyMgr.Line1Number;
```

Source: [Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7575/get-phone-number)

Make sure to add the `ReadPhoneState` permission in your manifest

Comment: That is just for Android. I guess Windows Phone and IOS have some limitations regarding getting users phone number.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fetch phone number for Android, IOS and Windows Phone.

**For Windows Phone**, you could get SIM MSISDN & IMSI number in Windows Phone Application. Please notice that you should manually edit your application `Package.appxmanifest` as follows:

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" 
    xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
    xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
    IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

......

<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="cellularDeviceIdentity" />
</Capabilities>
```

You could use [`MobileBroadbandModem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.mobilebroadbandmodem) class to get all `CurrentDeviceInformation`. For more you could refer this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942352/7254781). Note you could not use code where in above case reply directly. You need to create [`DependencyService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) for UWP project in your `Xamarin.Forms` library.

**For IOS**, [the short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193182/programmatically-get-own-phone-number-in-ios) is "no way". You have to ask the user to enter it manually. There are private APIs to access the user's phone number, but then Apple will reject your app.

Answer (score 0):

There is already plugin available for the same, You can use ContactsPlugin for Fetch Contact Number in Xamarin Forms,

Please check below link for the same. 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin

Thanks